# HttpServletRequest getParameterMap() get all parameter names

Tags: parameters, null, netflix-zuul, gateway

I was trying to get parametermap to do some signature verification, but parameters with null values are removed somehow by default in zuul gateway.

Since all parameters, even though with null values are needed in signature verification, after compute, it failed to match the signature string in input parameters.

How can I get all parameters, no matter their values are null or not?

Answer (score 0):

What if you read the information from the query string?

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
context.getRequest().getQueryString();
```

Comment: In fact, I tried before I posted this question. 
But by this way I hava to manually split params according to request method(POST or GET, etc), to which a way I don't prefer.